# It has compile time errors in this program. please help me to remove them

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.*;

  public class triangle
 {
  public static void main(String []args)
  {
      System.out.println("enter no. of test cases!!");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  int i,j,k,n,m,sum=0;


 m=sc.nextInt();

while(m>0)
{
System.out.println("enter the no. of lines!");
n=sc.nextInt();
int a[n][n] ;


 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   {
   a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
    } 

   }



 sum= a[0][0];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
 k=0;
   for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   {

 if(a[i][k]>a[i][k+1])
 {
 sum= sum + a[i][k];
 }
 else
 {
 sum=sum+ a[i][k+1];
 k++;
 }
 }
 }
 System.out.println("sum is :"+sum);

 m--;
}
}
}
```

I have tried it for hours but could not get it, the errors are going above my head, help me out.
these following  are errors:-
Main.java:17: error: ']' expected
int a[n][n];
      ^
Main.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
int a[n][n];
       ^
Main.java:17: error: ';' expected
int a[n][n];
        ^
Main.java:17: error: not a statement
int a[n][n];
         ^
Main.java:17: error: ';' expected
int a[n][n];
          ^

Comment: You will want to first go to any basic Java array tutorial as this is all well discussed there.

Comment: Do you know how arrays work in Java first in hand ?

Comment: got my error.. thanks @suresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a[n][n];` is not a valid array declaration.

It should be :

```
int[][] a = new int[n][n];
```